# Chat causes a violation of the CC license (I have pics!)

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, footer

The "people are chatting" side bar violates the page footer. And right over the CC license thingy, no less. See here:

[image]

Comment: Chrome 12.0.742.91, if that matters.

Comment: I guess it *is* Friday...

Comment: -1 no freehand circles. @Grace *Now* it's Friday.

Comment: @Adam - there. You'll have to settle for that.

Comment: @Jon'sEvilTwin: Sorry, editing conflict.  If you wish to dis the narwhal, feel free to roll back.  Just beware the horn.

Comment: @Won Looks like a shakespearian narwhal.  Alas poor CC license, I hardly knew ye!

Comment: @Won't - I don't fear your horny manatee. Uh, wait... maybe I should.

Comment: @Adam - edit conflict - now it's back the way it was meant to be.

Comment: @Jon'sEvilTwin: Just don't bend over at any point during the weekend.

Comment: @Jon Surely compromise can be reached?  Add the narwhal to you image.  And that's a flipper, as he orates his ode to the violated CC license, nothing more.

Comment: Hold please....

Comment: I wouldn't mind holding so much if you stopped using beiber as your hold music. baby baby baby AUGH GET IT OUT!

Comment: @Adam - Sorry, that was supposed to be Hendrix. I always get those two confused. Pic fixed. I hope that is what you had in mind.

Comment: Either those are the most amazing freehand circles or they are **not actually freehand circles** ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @Daniel - I positioned the curved text freehandedly. That counts.

Comment: Has this thing played out?  Can I close it as noise now?
 :P

Answer (score 3):

At some point (don't ask me when) we started only showing the chat ad when a question has a certain number of answers.

Accordingly, it shouldn't be possible for the page to be so short that the ad breaks into the footer.